# Request Too Large. Can't upload large video file to drive

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, google-drive-api

I have a script which uploads video files to my drive. Small video files are uploaded with sucess. But Large video files (up to 300MB) aren't uploaded and i receive a message "Request too large".
Is there any way to upload large file?

Comment: Are there any error codes that was generated on your end?

Comment: Request Entity Too Large
Error 413

Answer (score 0):

That depends heavily on cloud storage provider you use, is this a custom solution or is it like Google Drive or Dropbox?

Comment: I'm using Google drive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have exceeded your quota limits for your Google Cloud account as per this [document.](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota).

> If you exceed a quota with an API request, Google Cloud returns an HTTP 413 REQUEST ENTITY TOO LARGE status code.

But this may help resolve your issue.

> To request a higher quota limit by using the Google Cloud Console: Go to the Quotas page:
>
> Go to Quotas
>
> On the Quotas page, find the quota you want to increase in the Limit
> name column.
>
> You can use the Filter search box to search for your quota.
>
> Select the checkbox to the left of your quota.
>
> Click create EDIT QUOTAS. The Quota changes form displays.
>
> In the Quota changes form, enter the increased quota that you want for
> your project in the New limit field.
>
> Complete any additional fields in the form, and then click DONE.
>
> Click SUBMIT REQUEST.
>
> While the above procedure applies to most quota increase requests, you
> might encounter one of the following exceptions:
>
> In some cases, the Google Cloud Console redirects you to a separate
> form to request an increased limit. After you submit the form, Google
> Cloud acknowledges your request by email. Some quotas cannot be
> updated using the Google Cloud Console. If you find that you cannot
> change a quota from the console, request the increase from Cloud
> Customer Care. The Billing team does not handle quota limit increases.
> If your quota increase request requires approval, you can expect to
> receive an email from Google Cloud acknowledging receipt of your
> request. You can respond to this email if you need further assistance.
> Cloud Customer Care processes your request, typically within 2-3
> business days, and then sends you a second email notifying you whether
> the quota increase was approved or denied. The email provides the
> effective date of the increase, if applicable.
>
> To find out more about how the quota increase process works, see About
> quota increase requests.